# How do you find an overlapping match with a variable-length prefix using regex?

Tags: python, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds, ripgrep

I am trying to match tags like `TODO` inside comments in some code files using a regular expression. Consider for example the following file:

```
foo bar # TODO
bar foo quux   # TODO bar # TODO foo quux
quux # foo ## TODO foo # bar #  TODO quux
'# TODO\'' # TODO
```

Note that there might be multiple tags in one line as long as each one is preceded by `#`, so lines two and three should match twice. Furthermore, the prefixes before the first `#` (the actual code) may have arbitrary length; the same applies to what comes after each `TODO`. Apart from that there might be substrings like `# TODO` that are no comments (see line four; it should match once, the `# TODO` at the end).

I have been searching here on Stackoverflow and on other sites, but nothing seemed to answer a problem where you have **multiple overlapping matches and a variable length prefix before those matches**. I assume that the problem lies mainly in trying to use positive lookaheads/lookbehinds in conjunction with a context:

- `(?=#\s*TODO[^#]*)` does not work since it matches line four twice. This is why I say overlapping: It seems that you have to take the structure of the prefix into account when matching.
- I can match the prefix (actual code and comments without a tag) part with `^[^#']*('[^'\\]*(\\.[^'\\]*)*'[^#']*)*(#\s*(?!TODO)[^#]*)*` so that I get line four right, but this is a variable-length match, so using a positive lookbehind like `(?<=^[^#']*('[^'\\]*(\\.[^'\\]*)*'[^#']*)*(#\s*(?!TODO)[^#]*)*)(#\s*TODO[^#]*)` will result in an error on every regex engine as far as I know (and if working, would only match the first `# TODO` anyways).
- Matching the prefix and then using a positive lookahead like `^[^#']*('[^'\\]*(\\.[^'\\]*)*'[^#']*)*(#\s*(?!TODO)[^#]*)*(?=(#\s*TODO[^#]*)(#\s*(?!TODO)[^#]*)*)` does not work either since it matches only one occurrence of `# TODO`.

**To explain:** `\\.` matches an escaped character and `[^'\\]*` anything that is not an escape character and not a string delimiter, so `'[^'\\]*(\\.[^'\\]*)*'` matches any string literal. Using `[^#']*` outside of that string literal part means: Match anything that does not start a string or a comment, so the code part of a line is `^[^#']*('[^'\\]*(\\.[^'\\]*)*'[^#']*)*`. A comment segment that does not contain a tag can be found with `#\s*(?!TODO)[^#]*`, so the whole prefix can be matched with `^[^#']*('[^'\\]*(\\.[^'\\]*)*'[^#']*)*(#\s*(?!TODO)[^#]*)*`.

I use `ripgrep`, so this applies to PCRE/PCRE2 regular expressions.
I would, however, be interested in whether there is a solution in *any* regex dialect.

I know that I can match each line that has *at least one correct match* and post-process the results in some scripting language to extract each `TODO` from the lines, but I would like to know if it is possible to do this regex-only.

Comment: Perhaps like this `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'(*SKIP)(*F)|#+[^\r\n#]*TODO[^\r\n#]*` https://regex101.com/r/49NPut/1

Comment: Is this the question du jour? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66079810/9473764

Comment: @Thefourthbird Almost! Thanks a lot, you pointed me in the right direction. I didn't know about `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)` yet. This is the regex that works for me:
`"[^"\\\n\r]*(?:\\(?:$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.)[^"\\\n\r]*)*(?:$|")(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|'[^'\\\n\r]*(?:\\(?:$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.)[^'\\\n\r]*)*(?:$|')(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|#[\t\f\v ]*TODO[^\n\r#]*` https://regex101.com/r/kMiZtU/1 This is also safe when there are syntactically wrong string literals in the code.

Comment: @Thefourthbird If you'd like, you can add that as an answer and I would gladly accept it. Or should I answer my own question? What is the common way to go about this here?

Comment: @Nick Yes, that's strange. I didn't see that question before. I essentially tackle the same problem, but on Python and Makefile and with a different regex engine.

Comment: @julianbetz Perhaps you could shorten the pattern to a single `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` using `(?:"[^"\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\r\n]*)*"|'[^'\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^'\\\r\n]*)*'|["'][^"'\r\n]*$)(*SKIP)(*F)|#\h*TODO[^\r\n#]*` See https://regex101.com/r/mwl1HZ/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, that's good. But we have to check escaping with backslash in broken strings as well, otherwise we get matches inside: `(?:"[^"\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\r\n]*)*(?:"|\\?$)|'[^'\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^'\\\r\n]*)*(?:'|\\?$))(*SKIP)(*F)|#\h*TODO[^\r\n#]*` https://regex101.com/r/RZFPE0/1